# Codeception CEST acceptanse tests, how to rerun __bootstrap code before each test?

Tags: laravel, codeception, acceptance-testing

I am using Codeception for acceptance testing my code. What I need is to rerun the migrations and seeding (which I have specified in _bootstrap file) before each test. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move that code to _before method of `_support\Helper\Acceptance.php` if you want to run it before all acceptance tests.

http://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Hooks

```
namespace Helper;

class Acceptance extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function _before(\Codeception\TestInterface $test) {
    {
        // migrations
        // seeding
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand that I can use casual artisan commands in this methods.